# Accessing GUI window created by a Caliburn.Micro application on a background thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I've got a caliburn.micro WPF application, and I'm launching it from F# with a call to this function:

```
            public void LaunchGUI()
            {
                if (_guiWindow == null)
                {
                    var windowThread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // Create our context, and install it:
                            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

                            AppBootstrapper.Initialize();
                            var app = new App();
                            app.InitializeComponent();


                            //guiWindow = app.MainWindow;
                            //// When the window closes, shut down the dispatcher
                            //guiWindow.Closed += (s, e) =>
                            //    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
                            //guiWindow.Closed += (s, e) =>
                            //    guiWindow = null;
                            //guiWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                            //guiWindow.Show();
                            //guiWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                            //guiWindow.Activate();
                            // Start the Dispatcher Processing
                            Dispatcher.Run();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            LogMessage("error in gui thread: " + e);
                            //guiWindow.Close();
                            //guiWindow = null;
                        }

                    });
                    windowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    windowThread.IsBackground = true;
                    windowThread.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    _guiWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                    _guiWindow.Show();
                    _guiWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    _guiWindow.Activate();
                }
            }
        }
```

The issue is I need to have a reference to the main window so I can keep track of whether it's still open, etc., but it is always null (hence the commented code).  Note this works fine when running a "normal" MVVM app, and initializing it in a similar way:

```
    public void ShowGui()
    {
        if (guiWindow == null)
        {
            var windowThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // Create our context, and install it:
                    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
                        new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

                    guiWindow = new MainWindow();
                    // When the window closes, shut down the dispatcher
                    guiWindow.Closed += (s, e) =>
                        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
                    guiWindow.Closed += (s, e) =>
                        guiWindow = null;
                    guiWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                    guiWindow.Show();
                    guiWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    guiWindow.Activate();

                    // Start the Dispatcher Processing
                    Dispatcher.Run();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        guiWindow.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }
                    guiWindow = null;
                }

            });
            windowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            windowThread.IsBackground = true;
            windowThread.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            guiWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
            guiWindow.Show();
            guiWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            guiWindow.Activate();
        }
    }
```

My question is how do I get access to the main window created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// you get get the application main windows like this:

var _guiWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;

Comment: This is always null, whether I try to access it from the main thread or the GUI thread I created here.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like it was a threading issue (needed to wait a bit for it to be initialized).  Now I'm having the problem of trying to get at it from a different thread, but that's another topic.  Thanks.